# ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'articles'?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, cmd

I've created a directory name 'sp-node-mysql' and have a file called 'app.js' in it. My app.js file contains my connection code, and when I open the command prompt in my sp-node-mysql directory, I run the command 'mysql -u root -p' to establish a connection. Once connected, I try to use the database established in my app.js file. To do this, I type the command 'use articles', and then I get 'ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'articles''. Here's my app.js code:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

// First you need to create a connection to the db
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: 'articles'
});
connection.connect();

var articles = {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clearly stated:

```
Unknown database 'articles'
```

there is no database with the name `articles` on the connected server. Check what the exact name of the dataabase on the server and correct it in code and try again.

Comment: Forgive me as I am new to working with MySQL, but isn't my database in my app.js file? I thought that was where I was suppose to create my databases in node-mysql. Obviously I'm wrong, I just want to connect mysql with my js file so I can use it through node.